# Fastest way to search and remove/add line from/to file

Tags: php, performance, sorting, file-io, file-search

I'm wondering what the fastest way is to remove a specific line from a potentially large file, if it exists.

So for example I want the following line

```
abc
```

to be removed from the file

```
yxz
srtabc
abc
efg
```

becoming

```
yxz
srtabc
efg
```

Also, I want to add a line to the file, if it doesn't already exist.

The order of the file doesn't matter, and can be sorted if it provide a performance boost to the search.

Performance has never been my strong point, so I'm having a little trouble determining the best path to go down here.

Comment: Does the solution have to be programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't advice using `file_put_contents` or `file_get_contents`  because it would load all the contents of the file into PHP at once and this would not work for you if you are working with large file .

You can work with 2 files .. and read them a line after the other  ..... replace anything you need to replace then rename at the end .... This is only efficient when working with  very large file

Prof Of Concept

```
set_time_limit(0);

$baseFile = "log.txt";
$tempFile = $baseFile . ".temp";

touch($tempFile);

$findAndReplace = array("abc" => "","efg"=>"WWW");

$fileTemp = fopen($tempFile, "a+");
$fileBase = fopen($baseFile,"r");

while ( !feof($fileBase))  {
    $var = trim(fgets($fileBase));
    if (array_key_exists($var, $findAndReplace)) {
        var_dump($var);
        $var = $findAndReplace[$var];
    }
    if (!empty($var))
        fwrite($fileTemp , $var . PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($fileBase);
fclose($fileTemp);
unlink($baseFile);
rename($tempFile, $baseFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, don't use php.

But if you insist, and if all you need is a single replace operation, read in the entire file, then replace the line (as a string), and write it back. I.e. don't split the file into separate lines, which would make things slower than necessary.

This should to the trick:

```
$input = file_get_contents($filename_in);

$find = "abc..";

$find_q = preg_quote($find,'/');
$output = preg_replace("/^$find_q(\n|\$)/m","",$input);

file_put_contents($filename_out,$output);
```

It removes the lines containing exactly `$find`, including the trailing newline. In case the last line is not `\n` terminated, it will still be removed.

To test if a line is present, take a similar approach:

```
$find_q = preg_quote($find,'/');
if ( !preg_match("/^$find_q(\n|\$)/m",$input) )
{
    $input .= $find."\n"; // note: this assumes that $input is \n terminated
}
```